# SSRS WHERE Clause - data filtering

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm adding a WHERE clause in my ssrs expression but it seems to not work when i try preview the report:

I have created a Stored procedure and that's my dataset, here is the expression

```
=First(Fields!Names.Value, "mydataset") <===== I want to specify a WHERE Id = 5 Clause
```

**Final**

```
 =First(Fields!Id.Value = 5,Fields!Names.Value, "mydataset")
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Firstly, can this be filtered in the stored procedure?  Secondly, where is this expression within your report?  Is it within a tablix, chart axis, grouping function, etc?  The context is really important here.  Screenshots of the design would also be  very helpful.

Comment: Hi @iamdave I have the data in the dataset, but need to filter using WHERE clause

Comment: Like iamdave has says you need to provide more information in the question

Comment: Repeating what you have said in your question is not helpful.  Please add screenshots of your report design to your question.